# Populate SQL Server data in Excel (2010) spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel, odbc, vsto

I'm trying to populate the data extracted from SQL Server into Excel 2010. The code below works fine, but the difficulty is that I don't create an Excel spreadsheet programmatically, it is aleady exists and I make a request for data via plugin in Excel written in C#.
Even though I set the cursor to A10 cell, Excel starts filling-out the data from the very first cell and overwrites the header (that is already exists). Please help to fix.
Code:

```
OdbcConnection cnn;
                cnn = new OdbcConnection(azureConn);
                using (OdbcCommand command = cnn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = "{call sp_Get_Excel_Data(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", startDate);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", endDate);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startTime", startTime);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endTime", endTime);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@smp", smp);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reg", reg);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event", events);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", userId);

                    cnn.Open();

                    //DataTable
                    OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command);

                    //DataSet
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    adapter.Fill(ds);

                    //Cast to DataTable
                    DataTable dataTable = ds.Tables[0];

                    string[] colNames = new string[dataTable.Columns.Count];
                    int col = 0;

                    foreach (DataColumn dc in dataTable.Columns)
                        colNames[col++] = dc.ColumnName;

                    w = this.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
                    ws = (Worksheet)w.ActiveSheet;

                    Range hdrRow = (Range)ws.Rows[9];

                    hdrRow.Value = colNames;
                    hdrRow.Font.Bold = true;
                    hdrRow.VerticalAlignment = XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;

                    //Position the cursor
                    var range = ws.get_Range("A10");
                    range.Select();

                    //Inserting the Column and Values into Excel file
                    string data = null;
                    int i = 0;
                    int j = 0;

                    for (i = 0; i <= dataTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        for (j = 0; j <= dataTable.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                        {
                            data = dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                            ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = data;

                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hate to answer my own questions, but here is the solution (with optimized performance):

```
                    int column = 1;
                    foreach (DataColumn c in dataTable.Columns)
                    {
                        //Ninth row, starting from the first cell
                        ws.Cells[10, column] = c.ColumnName;
                        column++;
                    }

                    // Create a 2D array with the data from the data table
                    int i = 0;
                    string[,] data = new string[dataTable.Rows.Count, dataTable.Columns.Count];
                    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                    {
                        int j = 0;
                        foreach (DataColumn c in dataTable.Columns)
                        {
                            data[i, j] = row[c].ToString();
                            j++;
                        }
                        i++;
                    }

                    // Set the range value to the 2D array in Excel (10th row, starting from 1st cell)
                    ws.Range[ws.Cells[11, 1], ws.Cells[dataTable.Rows.Count + 11, dataTable.Columns.Count]].Value = data;
```